# mongrel_rails and pg version issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, windows-7, bundler, mongrel, pg

I am running Rails 3 and Ruby 1.8.7 on Windows. I am trying to use 'mongrel_rails start -e production' to run mongrel as proxy server for apache 2.2. I have apache running. When I issue the mongrel_rails command I get:

You have requested : pg >= 0.11.0.
Try running 'bundle update pg'

Doing the update does not resolve the issue. I have tried uninstalling and re-installing both pg and mongrel to no avail. I can find no references to this issue anywhere on the web and am totally stumped. Please help.

Update: I have also tried specifying pg >= 0.12.2 and I get the same result. I also tried running mongrel as a service, but couldn't get that to work either, but that is another issue, I suppose.

Comment: You might want to add 'bundler' to your tags, as this appears to be an issue with that software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final answer seems to be, there is no need to use a 'mongrel.conf' file in this configuration. DocumentRoot and ProxyPass url ('http://server-name:3000' in my case) are defined for Mongrel in the VirtualHost specification in httpd.conf file. The SeverName is set to 'server-name:80'.

Answer (score 0):

Update - The answer appears to be not to use 'mongrel_rails start' and just use 'rails server', however, I don't know if that will use the mongrel.conf I have in my app's config folder. And there does not seem to be a way to specify it on the command line.